# sorting ACCESS sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made another thread which solved my problem, however I got the report reviewed and they want it a revision. I will do my best to explain:

Consider the following:

[image]

I just need the ORDER BY part of the sql query. The three fields are `ACRNo`, `Type` and `Pty`.

1. I want it to sort by Type first.
2. I then want it to sort by Pty. However, I want the blank ones at the end. and the sorted ones on the top. (a normal `orderby` puts the blank ones on top).
3. After that has been sorted, I want the ACR numbers to be **Sorted *FOR ALL THE BLANK `PTY`***. I dont want the ACR's to be sorted (or i dont really care) when they have a pty attached to them. However when the Pty is blank, i want the highest acrnumber on top.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better way but here's a hackish method that should work unless you have Pty's starting with a bunch of z's:

```
order by Type, Pty + 'zzz',ACRNo desc
```

Comment: wow, that worked. Can you explain that quickly? nvmd, I figured it out!

Comment: Well, the only thing that's not straightforward is the Pty sorting, where you want blanks to come last...so you concatenate a 'zzz' to everything and now 'apple' becomes 'applezzz' and '' becomes 'zzz' so alpha sorting gives you what you want.

Comment: Just make sure that you never have any rows with a Pty value of zzz ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY
    type,
    IIF(pty IS NULL, 1, 0),
    pty,
    acrno
```

This assumes that by "blank PTY" you mean NULL. If you want actual empty strings to be at the bottom as well then you'll need to change it slightly:

```
ORDER BY
    type,
    IIF(NZ(pty, '') = '', 1, 0),
    NZ(pty, ''),
    acrno
```

SQL sorts on the columns (or expressions) in the order in which they are listed in the ORDER BY clause. So, the above will sort by "type" first, then for rows with the same value for "type" it will sort by the IIF() statement. In this case, the IIF() returns 1 if Pty has no value, otherwise it will return 0. So, the non-valued Pty rows will be sorted after those with a value. Then it goes on to sort by Pty (where all previous expressions in the ORDER BY have the same value) and ACRNo if they have the same Pty value.

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CASE WHEN [Rank] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'.

How would I tweak that?

Comment: Hey, I used kekekela's answer. But If i can avoid the hackish way, it would be awesome.

Comment: @masfenix - I don't think Access has Case statements, you probably need something like 
Switch(pty is null,1,pty is not null, 0)...or something along those lines, been many years and versions since I've used it

Comment: I changed it to use IIF() statements, which is apparently what Access uses. I'm also going to change the COALESCE to NZ(), which is supposedly the Access equivalent (for two terms at least)

Comment: Hi, it works but can you explain it a little bit? Thanks, trying to learn :).

Comment: I just added a brief explanation. I hope it makes sense.